# Is it possible to add the link of the parent record while sending a mail?

Tags: email, merge-field

Is it possible for us to send the link of the parent record in the mail? We have detail link to send the link of that current record so any workarounds to send the link of the parent?

Comment: what do you mean by parent record? Is that standard or custom object?

Comment: Okay I'm sorry for the ambiguous question. I have 2 custom objects 'A' and 'B' where 'B' is the child of A. Now I want to send a mail containing the details of B along with the link of its parent record. How do I do that?

Comment: lets see. If your parent object is A__c, child object is B__c, and B have field, called a__c, which is actually relationship name, so in your email you just need to put something like {!B__c.AId__c} to refer an id of salesforce record. So, it would be like https://login.salesforce.com//{!Test_Child_Object__c.Test_ObjectId__c} or https://test.salesforce.com//{!Test_Child_Object__c.Test_ObjectId__c} up to instance.

Comment: Yeah this can be done when I'm sending a mail through a trigger. Is there a way I can do this using workflow + email alert?

Comment: I know I can put in the merge field in the URL but I'm hard coating the base url which I don't want to do

Comment: you can make url as a static resource. or as a formula on object - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000i5yeAAA